# Rotate a direction vector by another direction

Tags: glsl, shader, hlsl, cg

I have a direction vector **(A)** that is pointing upward `(0, 1, 0)` and I want to be able to rotate it to another direction in a shader but only on one axis, in this case, the Z axis. This can be done using a vector **(B)** or a scalar.

As an example, without rotation the vector should point to the top `(0, 1, 0)`, but with a 90° clockwise rotation the vector should point to `(1, 0, 0)`.

[image]

Comment: You should multiply it with a rotation matrix to rotate it. For an arbitrary rotation axis you can use the formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle and for XYZ-Axis rotation the formula here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations

Answer (score 1):

If the rotation axis is always the z-axis (0, 0, 1) and the projection of the vector `A` into the xy-plane should be on the vector `B`, then the solution is:

```
vec3 A, B;

vec3 AB = vec3(length(A.xy) * normalize(B.xy), A.z);
```

A more general solution, with an arbitrary, normalized rotation axis `R` would be:

```
vec3 A, B;

vec3 R; // rotation axis (normalized)

vec3 A_r   = R * dot(A, R); // component of A, in the direction of R
vec3 A_prj = A - A_r;       // component of A, in the rotation plane

vec3 B_r   = R * dot(B, R); // component of B, in the direction of R
vec3 B_prj = B - B_r;       // component of B, in the rotation plane

vec3 AB    = length(A_prj) * normalize(B_prj) + A_r;
```